# Scala type mismatch between parent and child objects (Java-defined class Class is invariant in type T)

Tags: scala, inheritance, reflection, introspection

I have a (Scala) object hierarchy like so:

```
class Vehicle {
    ...
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
    ...
}

class Motorcycle extends Vehicle {
    ...
}
```

etc. I have a method that takes some input and returns the **class type** of the `Vehicle` subclass that is "best suited for it":

```
def chooseVehicleType(fizz : String) : Class[_ <: Vehicle] = {
    fizz match {
        case "buzz"     =>    classOf[Car]
        case "foo"      =>    classOf[Motorcycle]
        // etc.
        case _          =>    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(s"We don't support ${fizz} yet.")
    }
}
```

The problem here is that I get compiler errors on the `classOf` assignments:

> type mismatch; found : Classcom.me.myapp.model.Car required: Class[com.me.myapp.model.Vehicle] **Note: com.me.myapp.model.Car <: com.me.myapp.model.Vehicle, but Java-defined class Class is invariant in type T. You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as _ <: com.me.myapp.model.Vehicle. (SLS 3.2.10)**

Any ideas as to what is going on here, and what the fix is?

Comment: No, with this code you can't get this error (unless you are returning a `Car` instead of a `Class` somewhere in "etc.").

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change method return type? I just changed VehicleType with Vehicle in method return type and worked on me.

Comment: Sorry @user3816201 - that was a copy n paste error on my parent. Please see my edits, my code *does* return `Vehicle` (not `VehicleType`) afterall and still complains with the compiler message listed above.

Comment: i just copied and pasted. it is already working on me. Are you using which version of scala?